# Replace all characters of string to asterisks except first characters and space in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I`m was wonder if it is possible to hash sensitive data in mssql via function and to leave first character “as-is” for all the fields. Example:

"Jon Kirk” name should be extracted as J** K***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had posted a recursive solution at first. This is faster:

```
declare @name varchar(20) = 'Jon Kirk'

declare @loop int = len(@name)

while @loop > 1
select @name = stuff(@name, @loop, 1, 
case when substring(@name, @loop-1,2) like '% ' then ' '
     when substring(@name, @loop-1,2) like ' %' then substring(@name, @loop,1)
else '*' end), @loop+=-1

select @name
```

Comment: Found even more fast solution. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
declare @s varchar(50) = 'Jon kirk'

;with cte as (
    select 1 as i, cast (' ' + ltrim (@s) as varchar(50)) as s
    union all
    select i + 1
        , cast (
            case when substring (s, i, 2) like '% %'
            then s
            else stuff (s, i + 1, 1, '*') end
        as varchar(50))
    from cte
    where i < len (s)
)

select top 1 ltrim (s) as s
from cte
order by i desc
```

Here is the fastest solution (although it is not pretty at all):

```
declare @s varchar(50) = 'Jon kirk'

select left (
      left (@s, 1)
    + case when substring (@s, 1, 2) like '% %' then substring (@s, 2, 1) else '*' end
    + case when substring (@s, 2, 2) like '% %' then substring (@s, 3, 1) else '*' end
    + ...
    + case when substring (@s, 48, 2) like '% %' then substring (@s, 49, 1) else '*' end
    + case when substring (@s, 49, 2) like '% %' then substring (@s, 50, 1) else '*' end
    , len (@s) )
```

Comment: What about if first letter is in lower case.

Comment: I tried with recursive at first, using a simple while loop is much more effective. You are storing all the results in the memory before selecting a result from the list of modifications.

Comment: True. Your non-recursive solution occured much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your names are split up and do not contain spaces in the middle, you can hide sensitive information much quicker without doing weird loops:

```
DECLARE @t as varchar(20) = 'Billy'

SELECT CONCAT( LEFT(@t, 1), REPLICATE('*', LEN(@t) - 1) )
```

Outputs `B****`