# SQL-Server: Replace except first and last characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any ways to SELECT the first and last 2 characters and REPLACE all the other characters with * as shown below?

```
WA***RT
EX*** ***IL
CH***ON
BE******* *****AY
AP*LE
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But you want to keep space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all characters of string to asterisks except first characters and space in MSSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193228/replace-all-characters-of-string-to-asterisks-except-first-characters-and-space)

Comment: I would like to keep the space if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces skipped:

```
SELECT 
 name, 
 [hidden] = CASE WHEN LEN(name) <= 4 THEN name
                 ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(name, 2),REPLICATE('*', LEN(name)- 2),RIGHT(name,2))
            END
FROM #tab;
```

If you need spaces and there is **only one** you can use:

```
SELECT name, 
 [hidden] = CASE 
               WHEN LEN(name) <= 4 THEN name
               WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', name) > 0
               THEN STUFF(CONCAT(LEFT(name, 2),REPLICATE('*', LEN(name) - 2) ,
                         RIGHT(name,2)), CHARINDEX(' ', name),1, ' ')
               ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(name, 2),REPLICATE('*', LEN(name) - 2) ,RIGHT(name,2))
            END
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402916)**</kbd>

If you use version lower than `SQL Server 2012` concatenate string with `+`.

Comment: Awesome link for the LiveDemo.  I'll be sure to use that going forward!

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this and thinks to copy+paste without checking it, `LEN(name)- 4)` rather than `LEN(name)- 2)` (it currently adds an extra couple of *s)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  left(col,  2) +   REPLICATE('*',len(col)-4) +   right(col,2)  from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF`.

```
SELECT STUFF(col, 3, LEN(col)-4, REPLICATE('*',LEN(col)-4))
```

This doesn't preserve spaces.

To preserve N spaces, you can simply "add back spaces" with STUFF again:

```
SELECT col, 
masked = 
    coalesce(
    -- handle 2 spaces
    STUFF(STUFF(
      STUFF(col, 3, LEN(col)-4, REPLICATE('*',LEN(col)-4)),
    CHARINDEX(' ', col), 1, ' '),
    CHARINDEX(' ', col, CHARINDEX(' ', col)+1), 1, ' '),
    -- handle 1 spaces
    STUFF(
      STUFF(col, 3, LEN(col)-4, REPLICATE('*',LEN(col)-4)),
    CHARINDEX(' ', col), 1, ' '),
    -- normal masking
    STUFF(col, 3, LEN(col)-4, REPLICATE('*',LEN(col)-4)),
    -- too short to mask
    col
    )
```

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/402891)